Ergodic Markov chains and the ergodic theorem
If $f$ in an $L^1$ function on a probability space $\Omega$ and $T:\Omega\to\Omega$ is ergodic, then $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f(T^n)\to \int_{\Omega}fd\mu$ a.e.
If $\{1,...,k\}$ are the states of a Markov chain, on a probability space $\Omega$ and a stationary distribution $\mu$ on the state space, then $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{\{X_n=i\}}\to\mu(\{i\})$ a.e. for each state $i$.
Given that the distribution is stationary, is there a way see this Markov chain result from the ergodic theorem, by deriving some mapping $T:\Omega\to\Omega$ from the Markov process itself? Is there a $T$ such that $f=\chi_{\{X_1=i\}}$, then $f(T^n)=\chi_{\{X_n=i\}}$ for each $i$?

Yes, you can consider the space of histories:
$$
\Omega = S^\mathbb N
$$
with $S = \{1, ..., k\}$ the state space of the Markov chain. You can then equip it with the usual probability space structure of the Markov chain. For example, let $A(s_0,...,s_n)$ be the event:
$$
A(s_0,...,s_n) = \{\omega\in\Omega|\omega_0=s_0, ..., \omega_n = s_n\}
$$
the probability will be:
$$
P(A(s_0,...,s_n)) = \pi_{s_0}p_{s_0s_1}...p_{s_{n-1}s_n}
$$
For the ergodic theorem, $T$ is just the shift map:
$$
T:\omega\in\Omega\to(\omega_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\Omega
$$
You can check that $T$ preserves the measure $P$. Furthermore, if the Markov chain is ergodic, so is $T$ (in fact, ergodicity for Markov chain is a stronger condition).
For your example, you just need to take:
$$
f_s(\omega) = \chi_{\omega_0=s}
$$
The ergodic theorem gives:
$$
\frac1N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f_s(T^n(\omega))\to \int f_sdP=\pi_s
$$
This mapping between deterministic systems and Markov chain is a useful bridge. For example in the study of dynamical systems, this allows you to reduce the study of chaotic maps to Markov chains via Markov partitions.

I'm not sure I understand your notation. Does $f_i$ mean $f(T^i)$, where $T$ is the shift on state-space, and this also happens to equal $\chi_{{\omega_0=i}}$? In the version of the ergodic theorem I tried writing, there is a single function $f$ and the orbits converge to the average of that $f$.

I was using your notation. For clarity $s$ is the state that you choose for the counting

Once you’ve chosen the desired state, you just need to pushforward $f_s$ using $T$
